# How to keep media session notification on chrome android while loading

Tags: javascript, html, audio, android-mediaplayer, playlist

I've followed this google guide (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/media-session) and almost everything works fine.
But there is one unwanted behavior: when I change the audio source (either when an audio ends or user click "next track") the notification disappear, and reappear when the audio finished loading and is starting to play.
The desired behavior is keep the media notification inbetween tracks. Is there a way to do that?

I've tried setting navigator.mediaSession.playbackState to "playing" but no, no donut for me.

Comment: I've worked around this in the past by using two audio elements, and loading the next track on the secondary audio element beforehand

Answer (score 3):

It's probably not relevant anymore, but I've just fixed this in my own music player.

This is the commit that I fixed it in maybe it can help:
https://github.com/RuurdBijlsma/VueMusic/commit/c9eff89a2a0bb3ccf360d54c771065d7ce119501

Basically, besides the first `audio` element variable, I added a second variable called `backupAudio`, which is only relevant during the switch between audio sources. When I load a new track the `backupAudio` and `audio` contents are swapped (the `audio` becomes `backupAudio` and the `backupAudio` becomes `audio`), after this I set the src on the `audio` element and pause the `backupAudio` element.

Doing this ensures the notification works as expected for me. You should be careful with any event listeners you have on the audio elements though. I've previously implemented this in another application where quickly  skipping through tracks could cause two tracks to play at the same time, I've fixed that in my current music player. (also don't forget to set volume on both audio elements when changing it like I just did)

Comment: Essentially having a feature of fade in fade out between track changes would also be a workaround to this. A feature as a workaround to a problem 